# Python: Alphabetically sorting a list with letters and numbers in

Tags: python, sorting, alphabetical

I have a list

```
['2,alex', '5,james', '3,ben']
```

I need to alphabetically sort this.

The output should be

```
['2,alex', '3,ben', '5,james']
```

However using the `.sort` function does not work and will only sort it in a numerical order.

Comment: In your example there is no difference between "sort in numerical order" and "sort in alphabetical order."

Comment: Yes i just realized sorry, but i can assure you that it does not alphabetically sort. For example if an extra element was added into the list, say '10,charlie' that would end up at the end of the list as it sorts by numbers. Thanks for the comment :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `list.sort()` a key like below. If you want sort by the number, you can just use `str.split(',')[0]` to get it, and convert it to an integer:

```
>>> l = ['2,alex', '5,james', '3,ben']
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(',')[0]))
>>> l
['2,alex', '3,ben', '5,james']
```

If you need sort it by name, not the number, just use the same way but replace `[0]` with `[1]`, and remove the `int()` function:

```
>>> l = ['2,alex', '5,james', '3,ben']
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: x.split(',')[1])
>>> l
['2,alex', '3,ben', '5,james']
```

---

Let's see a clear example:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(x.split(',')[0]))
['5,james', '10,ben', '22,alex']
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: x.split(',')[1])
['22,alex', '10,ben', '5,james']
```

Comment: I think this is doing the opposite of what is wanted. They want to sort by the name, not the digit.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Yeah, and also remove the `int()`.

Comment: Thanks, this is great i did not expect the answer so quickly, this has made my code so much better thanks. And now i have an even better way for sorting in numerical order as well thanks loads. :)